# Expression-bodied members strange case

Tags: c#

I try to wrap my head around the concept of expression-bodied members feature.

Basic examples that I have found on the internet are quite clear, but I have encountered this specific piece of code and I don't know what it means exactly:

```
Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => calculator.Divide(5, 0));
```

Above example comes from a book about TDD techniques, that's why you can see the Assert class. The Divide method should throw `DivideByZeroException` and now we're testing this.

The puzzling part is `() => calculator.Divide(5, 0)`.

Could someone explain what exactly occurs there? The result of Divide function will embody the empty parenthesis?

Comment: That's a lambda method, not an expression-bodied method. It is asserting that the lambda method `calculator.Divide(5, 0)` will throw a `DivideByZeroException`. `()` is the arguments for the lambda, which is empty because there are none. In other cases you may see `(x, y)` or similar.

Comment: @DanWilson That has much more sense, thank you for the comment!

Comment: Like @DanWilson, this is a short way to define a function, and pass it to a function. you can assign it to a variable, and then call it like any another function. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Empty parenthesis is for zero parameter expressions

Comment: @ArturoO Giving you a +1 to help offest the downvotes as well as flagged it to see if a moderator feels the same. I feel this question is well crafted and I believe the OP has performed research.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks! I'm a newbie in C# and I'm still not familiar with many of its features. To me the syntax looked like expression-bodied members, thus the mistake.

Comment: @ArturoO It's ok. You are just trying to learn, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not an expression-bodied member *per se*. That's a *lambda expression*.  Lambdas were added to C# 3; the expression-bodied member feature was added much later and was designed to look like lambda syntax.

You can think of

```
Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => calculator.Divide(5, 0));
```

as being like

```
class Whatever 
{
  static double SomeFunction() => calculator.Divide(5, 0);
  ...
     ... later
     Func<double> f = SomeFunction;
     Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(f);
```

Does that make it more clear?

In short: `Assert.Throws` takes a *function*, it *calls* the function, and it *verifies that the function throws an exception*.  It is crucially important that it takes a *function that can be called*. You can't just say

```
Assert.Throws<Whatever>(calculator.Divide(5, 0))
```

because that throws *before* `Throws` is called!

Comment: Nicely crafted and well explained. +1

Comment: Good example, now I understand what this code means. Thanks!